# Why if I input a number more than 2 I don't get the loop?

Tags: java

So, my teacher gave us an activity. We need to make a program about a Fruit Basket using Stacks. So the problem is if I input to my question more than 2 "How many fruits would you like to to catch?",  I'm not able to input anything after the first attempt.

```java
public class FruitBasket {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);

        Stack <String> fruits = new Stack <String>();
        
        System.out.println("Catch and Eat any of these Fruits: ('Apple' , 'Orange' , 'Mango' , ' Guava ' ) ");
        System.out.print("How many fruit would you like to catch?");
        int size = scan.nextInt();
        
        
        System.out.println("Choose a fruit to catch. Press A , O , M or G.");
        scan.nextLine();
        
        int x = 1;
        
        do {
        String input = scan.nextLine();
        System.out.println("Fruit " + x + " of " + size+ ": " + input);
        x++;
        
        
        switch(input) {
        
        case "a":
            fruits.add("Apple");
            break;
        
        case "o":
            fruits.add("Orange");
            break;
            
        case "m":
            fruits.add("Mango");
            break;
            
        case "g":
            fruits.add("Guava");
            break;
            
        }
        
        
        }while(x == size);
        
        System.out.println("Your basket now has: "  + fruits);
        System.out.println(); //Spacing
        
    }
}
```

Comment: `while (fruits.size() < size)` seems more readable, eliminates the need for `x` variable and also naturally handles the case of input not in `[a,o,m,g]` - i.e. keeps getting input.

Answer (score 4):

The issue here is your condition in your `do-while` loop. Your current condition is, that the loop shall only be repeated if `x == size`.

You start with a `x = 1` and you increment `x` inside the `do` block of your `do-while` loop. This means, the only way that the loop is repeated is if you input `size` to be `2`. Because then, your specified condition of `while(x == size)` is `true` at the time of the check.

In all other cases, the condition is `false` and your loop does not repeat.

You might want to change the loop condition as

```java
while(x <= size)
```

to loop `size - 1` amount of times, which runs the `do` block a total of `size` times.